# function is not called from change event using jquery ui slider in angular

Tags: angular

I am using jQuery UI slider in Angular and slider is initialized and being slide properly.however, when i call another function from change event then its not called and giving error as below :

> TypeError: this.getSelected is not a function

HTML :

component.ts :

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    $("#rangeSlider1").slider({
           range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 333,
            step: 10,
            values: [0, 333],
         change: function(event,ui){
              this.getSelected(ui);
         }
    })
}

getSelected(){
   // further actions need to execute on change of the slider.
}
```

Here, `getSelected()` is another function which i need to call when slider range is change, but this gives me an error as mentioned above. Please note, I can't put the whole code of `getSelected` function to slider initialization.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `change` function `this` does not refer to the component, instead of that it refers to `undefined`.

You need to use *arrow function* which preserves the outer `this`.

```
change: (event, ui) => {
    this.getSelected(ui);
}
```